# In Excel: counting the same value in multiple columns by date recorded

Tags: excel, indexing, match, countif

I am trying to count the same value over multiple columns but only if they appear in a certain date in the format **'YYYY-MM'**

I have gotten so far through bloody mindedness (code below) but it only looks at one column and counts them when I want to look at both columns but only if they fall on a certain date.

As an example, I have 3 columns. The first column 'A' has **YYYY-MM** values, the second 'B' is called Partner1 filled with names and the third column 'C' is called Partner2 again filled with names.  I want to find out how many times 'Dave' (F2) appears in both columns on a certain date.

e.g. How many times has Dave been a partner in 2016-04 (A17)?

Thanks for reading.

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A17,INDEX(B2:C10,,MATCH(F2,B2:B10,0)),"Dave")
```

Date: 2016-04

no. times Dave has a partner: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7=A17)*(B2:B7="Dave")*(C2:C7="Dave")*1)

=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7="2016-04")*ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B7,{"Dave","Lisa"},0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2:C7,{"Dave","Lisa"},0)))
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: This works as well. Thank you. Do you know if there is a way to adjust this formula to look for multiple names in a combined count (e.g. how many times does Dave and/or Lisa occur in 2016-04?) Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 `COUNTIFS` like this -

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A10, A17, B2:B10, "Dave") + COUNTIFS(A2:A10, A17, C2:C10, "Dave")`

Comment: Solved! Thanks so much. I though I needed to potentially repeat somewhere but wasn't 100% which part of the formula. Thanks again, Imtiaz.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a construct like below.

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A17,B2:B10,"Dave",C2:C10,"Dave")`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it just comes back with a zero as I think it's looking at whether Dave appears in both columns on the same row when it will only appear once in either. Is there a way to look for if Dave appears only once in either column (row non-specific) and count if true?